# Order a dataframe by column values with R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe given by

```
x <- c(1,3,4,5,6,9,7,8,9,2,1)
y <- c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C","A", "B", "C", "C", "C")

df <- data.frame(x,y)
```

I want to order it with respect column y.

I did something like

```
orderdf <- df[order(df$y),]
```

and I got on the y columns

```
AAABBCCCCCC
```

but actually I want to order it also by numerosity so on my y column I want to obtain

```
BBAAACCCCCC
```

How can I do it?

Moreover I would also like to count how many (I have no clue about this) to obtain:

```
B 2


A 3


C 6
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
# construct count variable
df$count <- ave(df$x, df$y, FUN=length)
# order it up
df[order(df$count, df$y),]
```

Another nice way to obtain counts is using `table`:

```
table(df$y)
```

Comment: I was going to post the exact same answer :D (you should only remove the minus before df$count ;) )

Comment: I removed the minus in `-df$count`since it yields `CCCCCCAAABB` (i.e. the opposite order) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  mutate(count = n()) %>%
  arrange(count, y) %>%
  select(-count)
```